# Jasper Report Theme

Tags: jasper-reports

does any one knows about where to find **Jasper Reports ready made themes** as we can find for other tools. i mean to say if i can find best font combinations with color combinations for various section of Jasper reports. so i can use it as a Jasper style Template such as we use CSS for web pages. if anyone uses it for his/her projects please guide me. i want to make pixel perfect professional reports using Jasper but i am always confusing for styling it.

Thank You
Mihir Parekh

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any place where you can download themes for Jasper Reports. They do support what they call Jasper Reports Templates, so I assume it would be possible.

My suggestion is for you to sit down and determine what you think is best, and then create your own template. They can be externalized, so that if you need to change it, you just do it in one place.

See this Question on [External Styles in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196668/external-styles-in-jasperreports) and here [Jasper Reports Sample](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/templates/index.html) they provide on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find different default template in iReport current version is 4.x

### Some use full links :

1. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydJMb7W2uKs
2. http://jasperforge.org/website/ireportwebsite/IR%20Website/ir_design_a_report.html?header=project&target=ireport

I think it will helpful for u...